# Sending HTML based email body using android intent

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail, html-email

I need to send HTML based content to email app using android intent extra . Its accept some tags like `<BR>` but its not showing any anchor link or `<H1>`, its shows like simple text .

`EDITED : I have tried with gmail app`

I have attached my code its in kotlin language

```
   val body="<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">clicke me</a>"
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
            intent.setType("text/html")
            intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:") // only email apps should handle this
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subjecnew")
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(body))
            if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                startActivity(intent)
            }
```

Comment: It is up to the email client how to interpret `EXTRA_TEXT`. Different apps will have different levels of support. Also note that neither `EXTRA_TEXT` nor `EXTRA_SUBJECT` are documented for `ACTION_SENDTO`, so many apps will ignore those extras entirely.

Comment: I have tested using gmail and Extra text and subjects are working, but it did not  show the content as HTML it treat it as normal string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google has removed that feature from gmail application so its not possible to send  tag content to gmail . Alternate is you can send that data from server

Answer (score -1):

```
final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,      
Uri.parse("mailto:"));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The Subject");
shareIntent.putExtra(
Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
    .append("<p><b>Some Content</b></p>")
    .append("<small><p>More content</p></small>")
    .toString())
);
```

Comment: No luck in gmail app its show plain text even bold is not working .